# How is "user attribution" defined?

Tags: users, terminology

I am working on a concept around this topic and would like to clarify its meaning before designing a solution for it.

Are there existing definitions of the terms *"user attribution"*? What is it really?

Comment: Are you talking about persona modelling or attributing content rights to users?

Comment: Is attributing content rights something like: a user who contributes a lot "earns" the possibility to moderate other users content?

Comment: No, it's more like "Fred wrote this article."

Comment: Yes, then I am talking about attributing content rights to users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would define user attribution as:

> The process of granting a user attribution of origination, authorship,
>   ownership or any other associated right in relation to a specific
>   piece of content.

I would suggest you look at the creative commons project for an example of how the process of attribution can be explored.

http://creativecommons.org/